# Error opening /sys/class/power_supply/bms/resistance

Tags: android, moto

> When i launch app then below error print in debug log, i want to find out is it app side issue or device side, i am new in android development so can anyone confirm this why below log is came ?

**Device Moto G3**

```
12-28 11:09:31.190 6380-6403/? E/MC_LineReader: Error opening /sys/class/power_supply/bms/resistance
                                                java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/power_supply/bms/resistance: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
                                                    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader.<init>(LineReader.java:20)
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader$1.<init>(LineReader.java:53)
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader.firstLineReader(LineReader.java:53)
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.util.BatteryUtils.getBatteryResistance(BatteryUtils.java:130)
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.action.BatteryLevelAction.onReceiveImpl(BatteryLevelAction.java:42)
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.util.BackgroundReceiver$1.run(BackgroundReceiver.java:14)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
                                                    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66) 
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader.<init>(LineReader.java:20) 
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader$1.<init>(LineReader.java:53) 
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader.firstLineReader(LineReader.java:53) 
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.util.BatteryUtils.getBatteryResistance(BatteryUtils.java:130) 
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.action.BatteryLevelAction.onReceiveImpl(BatteryLevelAction.java:42) 
                                                    at com.motorola.motocare.util.BackgroundReceiver$1.run(BackgroundReceiver.java:14) 
                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: I am facing same problem, please post solution if you got any

Answer (score 0):

It is a device issue most likely related to its SD-card. I had the same problem with the same device when SD-card was removed. To get rid of it try to:

- Put SD-card back or;
- Go to `Settings-> Storage and USB` and check if    there is still a
  link to SD-card and choose `Forget` option for it,    but be aware
  that it will remove all references to data which were    stored on
  it.